# pthread_create error code 11 even with a few threads

Tags: c, multithreading

So I basically have code that is basically

```
pthread_t cpu[10];


while (a certain condition){

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
   pthread_create(&cpu[i],NULL,(a function), NULL);
}
```

this code should be running about 10 threads at a time however, after running the while loop a certain amount of times it says their is a pthread error with code 11. I know I am running the threads multiple times however, shouldn't only 10 instances be happening?

Comment: A [mre]  would be helpful.

Comment: Do you ever call `pthread_join()` on your threads?  If not, it's likely you are piling up a lot of leaked thread-resources very quickly, and soon you hit a resource-limit and error out.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I am not calling pthread_join() all the time but I do not want my program to wait for a thread to complete

Comment: @mike91827 But you still hit the resource limit, since you're continuously creating threads in your while loop. Either stop creating threads or at least once in a while, delete some.

Comment: Btw: "shouldn't only 10 instances be happening?". What makes you think that? `pthread_create` expects as the first argument a pointer to a `pthread_t` to store the thread id in it, that's about it. If you pass several times the same address, then that many times, an id will be stored there, of course overwriting the previous ones. That is not a good idea either.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük is the only to delete threads through pthread_join()? Also are you saying that if I call pthread_create(&cpu[0],NULL,function,NULL); twice two threads are being created despite both threads having the same address

Comment: Yes, `pthread_join` waits for the thread to terminate and afterwards gives the resources back to the system. see [man pthread_join](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html), particularly the **Notes** section. Yes that is exactlly what is happening. Btw. you specify an address where the thread id should be stored, nothing more. The system executes two threads (by invoking the specified function) but the ids of the threads are stored only in one place.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük But i Know pthread_join waits for a thread to finish however, i still want the program to run even the thread is not completely done yet

Comment: You have a limit. You are exceeding that limit. You want only 10 threads? Create ten, not ten million. Then if you think that the time has come to delete those threads, finish them off with a call to pthread_join. Meanwhile, do whatever you think should be done. If you want to reuse the threads, think about a threadpool and worker threads (a list of tasks, which will be processed one at a time by each thread).

Answer (score 1):

The limit on threads is being reached because the program is calling `pthread_create()` in a loop, constantly spawning more threads, without ever calling `pthread_join()` to clean up the resources of the existing threads.  This quickly fills up the process's threads-table, at which point `pthread_create()` starts to error out because there is no more room in the process's threads-table for any more threads.

To avoid that problem, you need to modify the code so that it only summons a finite (and reasonable -- read: dozens, not hundreds or thousands) number of threads into existence at one time.

A simple calling-pattern to achieve that would look something like this:

```
pthread_t cpu[10];

while (a certain condition){

   // spawn 10 threads
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
      pthread_create(&cpu[i],NULL,(a function), NULL);
   }

   // at this point all 10 threads are running

   // wait until all 10 threads have exited
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
      pthread_join(&cpu[i], NULL);
   }
}
```

Another common (and somewhat more elegant) approach would be to use a thread-pool instead of spawning and joining threads.  That's often preferable because it avoids the overhead required to constantly create and then tear down threads, and because it means that as soon as a thread has finished computing job A, it can immediately grab job B out of the pending-jobs-queue and start working on it -- unlike the code shown above, which has to wait for all 10 threads to complete before it can spawn 10 more.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", strerror(11));
    return 0;
}
```

Gives on my system: Resource temporarily unavailable
Again on my system: EAGAIN is defined as 11 (errno.h).

[man pthread_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) states as possible error return codes:

**EAGAIN**

> Insufficient resources to create another thread.

**EAGAIN**

> A system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.  There are a number of limits that may trigger this error: ...

The reason for that was already answered by Jeremy Friesner in the comments section above.

Comment: FYI there's an `errno(1)` tool in the `moreutils` package on some distros.